# How to render a Youtube thumbnail in a template in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using the following modules:

- media
- media_youtube
- Styles

and would like to render a thumbnail of a Youtube video in a template (.tpl). Which theme function should I use and with what params?

My best quess would be something like:

```
$my_media['style_name'] = 'unlinked_thumbnail';
print theme('file_styles',$my_media);
```

where $my_media is an array containing fid,uri,filename,filemime etc.

Since i'm very new to Drupal, all my attempts to make sense of the modules source code have failed. I feel like I have tried all possible combinations of style names defined in the youtube and styles module without getting any output.

Rendering the video itself however works just fine using

```
print theme('media_youtube_video',$my_media);
```

How do you guys do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Digging around in the `media_youtube` module code there's a function that will build this up for you in `includes/media_youtube.formatters.inc` called `media_youtube_file_formatter_image_view()`. You can use code like the following to render the thumbnail image:

```
// Make sure the correct include file is loaded
module_load_include('inc', 'media_youtube', '/includes/media_youtube.formatters.inc');

// Load the file
$file = file_load($my_media['fid']);

// Set up the settings array with your image style
$display['settings'] = array('image_style' => 'unlinked_thumbnail');

// Get the render array for the thumbnail image
$image_render_array = media_youtube_file_formatter_image_view($file, $display, LANGUAGE_NONE);

// Render it
print render($image_render_array);
```

Comment: can you tell where to add this piece of code either in vide tpl or something else?

Answer (score 4):

One more example, which makes possible to render video thumbnail (vimeo, youtube, qbrick, etc.) with your custom image style.

`$file` - File object that you can easily get from media field.

```
$wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($file->uri);
$image_uri = $wrapper->getLocalThumbnailPath();

$image_rendered = theme('image_style', array(
  'style_name' => 'YOUR_IMAGE_STYLE_HERE',
  'path' => $image_uri
));
```

Please note, that if you want to render also image, than you need to check `$file->type` if it's `video` or `image`, because it will use different wrapper objects with different methods.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to print both thumb+video you could do this :

```
<?php print render($content['field_your_field']); ?>
```

If you in a tpl and want to use $variables - it will be something like:

```
<?php print render($variables['content']['field_url']['#object']->content['field_video']);?>
```

Hopu u can use it...