# how to render youtube video in drupal

Tags: drupal, youtube, drupal-7

How can I render a YouTube source in Drupal? The field which contains the informations contains this:

```
 [fid] => 59
                            [display] => 1
                            [description] => 
                            [uid] => 1
                            [filename] => Retarded running giraffe
                            [uri] => youtube://v/Cn59jVAHLTs
                            [filemime] => video/youtube
                            [filesize] => 0
                            [status] => 1
                            [timestamp] => 1340129371
                            [type] => video
                            [rdf_mapping] => Array
```

Is there any way to render this information to a YouTube-Video embed code ? Something like this:

```
drupal_render_youtube('youtube://v/Cn59jVAHLTs');
```

Is there any solution to solve this without writing the hole embed code by my self ?

Comment: Did you consider using the Media: YouTube Plugin?

Comment: Yes, i do - but i need only to grab the youtube field in my own template - i dont render the hole node. When i render the hole node the plugin render the URL correctly.

Comment: Drupal core certainly doesn't have anything like this. Have a look at [Media Youtube](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) like @Karthik suggests, and [Video Embed Field](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field)...they both have that functionality, you can just copy it to your own module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These will help...

[How to render a Youtube thumbnail in a template in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197184/how-to-render-a-youtube-thumbnail-in-a-template-in-drupal-7)

http://drupal.org/project/mediaelement

Comment: Thanks! With theme('media_youtube_video',$my_media); it works! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Or someting like this:

```
<?php print render($variables['content']['field_url']['#object']->content['field_video']);?>
```